# Can a t-test p-value be <.05 when the CI for cohen's d includes zero?

Tags: confidence-interval, p-value, effect-size, cohens-d

Is it possible for a t-test p-value to be <.05 when the confidence interval for cohen's d includes zero?

Comment: Do you have an example?

Comment: What is the connection between the t-test and Cohen's d?

Comment: Why not? They show different things. Small absolute difference, big variation and big sample size - you'll get 'significant' t-test but misirable effect size.

Comment: Can anyone explain in a way that might help me understand WHY this is the case? Is there a reference for this?